# Ggplot axis labels not showing in shiny

Tags: ggplot2, shiny, label, axis

I'm quite new to Shiny and totally new to plotting in Shiny, and I encounter an issue with my plots axis labels when using ggplot. They're just not displaying when I run the app. I apologise if the question has been asked before, I swear I did search for answers before asking :-)

Here is a super simplified ggplot example that is not working for me:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      plotOutput("ggplot")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })
  
  output$ggplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(cars) +
      geom_point(mapping = aes(x = speed, y = dist))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is the output I get:
[Output while running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggkni.png)

As you can see, the plot with `plot` has axis labels, but not the ggplot one.

What did I do wrong? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: [It works for me](https://i.imgur.com/tM2ylMH.png), so not sure what the problem is! A few possible things to try - update `ggplot2` and `shiny` packages; run plotting code outside of shiny to see what difference that makes; change screen size in case it's a zooming/size problem; run just code in a fresh R session in case you've set defaults for theme elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just found out it's an even weirder issue. The labels show on my laptop, but when I connect my laptop to my additional screen, they don't show on the screen. When I move the app window to my laptop screen, they reappear. I'm puzzled... but at least it's not an R problem!

Comment: Same happened to me! Thanks for the comment i

Answer (score 1):

When I got a similar issue connecting a Macbook Pro with an Apple M2 chip to an external monitor (Shiny ggplot2 legends showing on internal screen but not when dragging the window to the external monitor), I solved the issue by installing this tool: https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34612081)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Intel mac. Installing Better Display App and changing settings of my external monitor to lower aspect ratio with forced HiDPi fixed this. So enter Display Mode in the App and then go to the settings for the external monitor. Filter to include HiDPi and 16:10. 1440 X 900 shows up, select this for external monitor and as it then matches the retina display it fixes the problem. Plot text now shows up in the Shiny App on External Monitor.

The external monitor is 16:9 by default, so forcing to match retina 16:10 can give an option for 1920 x 1200 but its not great. I've stuck with the 1440 x 900 for now, not ideal and lacking sharpness but workable until I get a matching retina monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help others with the same problem, but for me using a bigger font size was the solution (I guess fonts too small are not taken into account)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).